# Merging 2 xlsx files in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, xlsx

Why does the first code work correctly, but the second does not?

```
df2 = pd.read_excel("123.xlsx")
data = pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx")
data.to_csv("jj.csv", index=False)
data1 = pd.read_csv("jj.csv") 
df3 = pd.merge(df2, data1, on='Product_Code',how='outer')
```

The shape of df2 is 2417x2, and the shape of data1&data is 6663x26.
The shape of df3 is 6742x27 which I know is correct.

```
df2 = pd.read_excel("123.xlsx")
data = pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx")
df3 = pd.merge(df2, data, on='Product_Code',how='outer')
```

The shape of df3 is 8852x27. Ideally I do not want to have to create a csv file and then open and read it - so how can I get the second code's merge to work?

When I print data and data1, they look exactly the same.

Comment: maybe it has to do with encoding when you write to csv?

Comment: No worries, I will just save the file as a csv.